# Are the top users paid by Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Are the top users paid by Stack Overflow? I do not expect something like that but this could be helpful to all community as we are all benefiting from the great posts here. It would create a similar effect like in youtube.com where people are making videos for making money and we can even find a tutorial on *"how to eat a dragon fruit"* or *"programming 2003 honda accord keys"*.

Comment: [tl;dr](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169210/164356)

Comment: Stack Overflow wishes that Jon Skeet works for them.

Comment: I do suggest that top users should be awarded a profile banner trim and a profile picture border. Depending on the user ranking, the trim and border color varies from bronze, silver, gold, platinum to diamond.

Comment: @YilongWang not sure there is really any added benefit here. We always say that the users are inconsequential and the content is what is important. I feel like doing this might send the wrong message (+ what is "diamond" as a color?)

Comment: @ryanyuyu any source beside [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)?

Comment: Way to plug your videos, dude.

Comment: **Me**: _walk into a job interview in my pajamas_ ... **Employer**: "What skills do you have? What can you offer our company?"  **Me:** "I haz SO account with 200k rep" ... **Employer**: "Hired."

Comment: It'd be an interesting experiment, to see what happens with Stack Overflow when response to content is monetised. The first thing that will happen is that banners will appear all over the place to work around the bug that money is not free.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

The top users are not paid by Stack Overflow, unless they happen to be Stack Overflow employees, at which time yes, they are.

A very large majority of top users are not Stack Overflow employees.

Comment: Wait, we're supposed to get paid?!?!? Who knew!!

Comment: @bluefeet - were you not sent your ration of bacon?

Comment: BACON! No, I didn't get any BACON!!

Comment: How close to Jin do you live? I am overseas, so it is not as easy for him to get to mine, @bluefeet

Comment: Does that mean I have to give the money back?

Comment: Next Question: *What are getting vegetarian moderators instead of their daily ration Bacon?*

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt - [Vegetarian bacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarian_bacon), what else.

Comment: @bluefeet: Since when did you eat land meat?

Comment: [Hmm bacon](https://i.giphy.com/media/wOkzr0DP7jyOA/giphy.webp) _disclaimer: I'm not a canadian_